# SQLAlchemy attribute-mapped collection and missing values?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

With the following mapped collection setup, which maps Person with any number of attributes in another table using dictionary syntax for access:

```
class FormField(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'), nullable=False)
    keyword = Column(String(255))
    payload = Column(Text)


class Person(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    fields = relationship("FormField",
              collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('keyword'),
              cascade="all, delete-orphan")
```

The normal usage (see also documentation http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/collections.html#dictionary-collections ):

```
person = Person()
person.fields["mykey"] = FormField("mykey", "Some payload")
```

It is also very simple to search for persons having specific attribute value. The question however is, how to search for persons, which do not have an attribute at all, especially, as part of a more complex query?

One way could be to always create all attributes and put NULL into, say, payload, but is it possible to **efficiently** search for totally missing attribute? For example, if query should dig out persons, which have attrbute "a" having value "A", attribute "b" having value "B", and missing attribute "c"?

```
db.session.query(Person).join(FormField).join(FormField_alias)
    .filter(FormField.keyword == "a", FormField.payload == "A")
    .filter(FormField_alias.keyword == "b", FormField_alias.payload == "B")
    # ???
    .all()
```

I guess, it's not as simple as adding one more filter. But what then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a bunch of [EXISTS expressions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#using-exists) instead of inner joins:

```
In [48]: session.query(Person).\
    ...:     filter(Person.fields.any(and_(FormField.keyword == 'a',
    ...:                                   FormField.payload == 'A')),
    ...:            Person.fields.any(and_(FormField.keyword == 'b',
    ...:                                   FormField.payload == 'B')),
    ...:            not_(Person.fields.any(FormField.keyword == 'c'))).\
    ...:     all()
```

For example in Postgresql the EXISTS and NOT EXISTS produce semi- and antijoins that should be plenty efficient with proper indexes.

Comment: So I guess I need `person_id` as well added to the inside of `and_`?

Comment: No, it is implied from the relationship.